# Compare today's date against information from a CSV. If matching, execute command

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, group-membership

I've got a script that asks for a `Username` and `DateRemove (MM/DD/YYYY)`.  This input is exported to a `config.CSV` file with the `-Append` function and the `CSV` format is `Username,DateAdd,DateRemove`.

I'm wanting to create a second PS file to run as a daily scheduled task.  This is where I'm lost and hoping for help...

I'd like to reference this `config.CSV` and compare the `DateRemove` to the current date, if there's a match I want to take the `Username` and execute "`Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName -Members $User`", if there's no match I want it to do nothing.

Tried a single PS script creating a "removal" job but this failed and used variables as arguments in my scheduled task.  Not to mention it was going to create 100s of task scheduler jobs. Which has led me to one PS file for user input and one file for scheduled job referencing a "source" file.

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the username you want to add to group'
if ($User) {
    Write-Host "$User will be added to the group"
} else {
    Write-Warning -Message "We need a username to run this script"
}
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Group -Members $User

$Date = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter removal date'
if ($Date) { 
    Write-Host "$User will be removed from group on $Date"
} else {
    Write-Warning -Message "We need a date to run this script"
}
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Username = $User
    DateAdd  = Get-Date -Format g
    DateRemove = $Date
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\config.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

```
$Date = Get-Date
$Config = Import-Csv C:\config.csv
Foreach($DateRemove in $Config) {
$DateRemove = $DateRemove.Date
if "$DateRemove" -eq $Date
```

Now I'm just confused..

Comment: Your check of the input `$User`/`$Date`is useless if you continue nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like the following:

```
$today = [datetime]::Today
Import-Csv C:\config.csv | ForEach-Object {
  if ([datetime] $_.DateRemove -eq $today) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $_.Username 
  }
}
```

Note that group information isn't part of the CSV you create in your question, so I'm assuming that it is stored in variable `$group` here.

`[datetime]::Today` returns today's date at midnight (the *start* of the day), i.e., *without a time-of-day component*<sup>Thanks, [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings).</sup> and, given that the date read from the CSV  file (`[datetime] $_.DateRemove`) won't have one either, the `-eq` comparison works as intended.

Generally, avoid comparing *string* representations of time stamps (`"$DateRemove"`), due to variations in formatting and lack of precision.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @mrn3ff; my pleasure.